# Scrollbar coming in safari (windows) even if height is increased

Tags: html, css

I am creating a site for client and a section inside footer is producing scrollbars.
I had increased the height of wrapper and given overflow as hidden but the stubborn bars are not going..

Can anyone help me.. the web page is http://imajination.in/00dev/ingageDev/
Chech the footer

Answer (score 0):

i've tried safari, firefox, ie, chrome and opera, all with the newest versions and on win7 and i can't see any scrollbars on the footer... maybe you solved the problem already.

edit:
i forgot to mention I had checked in safari as well.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots and tell us wich version of safari you're sing and on which os?

Answer (score 0):

Hum I've checked in safari as you said and there is no scrollbar.
I use safari (5.1.7)